# JSON corrupted attributes

Tags: javascript, json, attributes

I'm having difficulties understanding behavior of Javascript.

Code:

```
function getPosition(element){
    var position = {
        x:$(".line div").has(element).index(),
        y:$(".line").has(element).index()
    };
    console.log(position.y);
    console.log(position)
    return position;
}
```

Now while calling it from function I'm getting results like this:

```
0

Object
x: 8
y: 3
```

What I don't understand is how is it possible to change object attributes when trying to access it via object reference, but not directly.

But when I call same function from console I get this:

```
0

Object
x: 8
y: 0
```

This is the same element passed to function. And it seems that it fails always when X or Y is 0(zero), when it's another number it's ok.

Could anyone explain what I'm doing wrong? Or is it somekind of JS bug? O_o

EDIT:

So I finally found out what the problem was. I always thought that I was passing values but unfortunately I was wrong all the time. During some searches on stackoverflow, I found [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language) about JS values and references.

If anyone is interested and too lazy to read the topic, you can look at this example. It's pretty much self explanatory.

```
function test(){
    var a = 5;
    var b = a; //b now has value of 5
    console.log("a:"+a+":b:"+b);
    b = 4;//a still has value of 5 and b is assinged to 4
    console.log("a:"+a+":b:"+b);
    var c = {val:1};
    var d = c; //d now has reference to c
    d.val = 2; //c.val changes because it is a reference
    console.log(c);
}
```

EDIT2:
oh and by the way, how can I mark my question as answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally found out what the problem was. I always thought that I was passing values but unfortunately I was wrong all the time. During some searches on stackoverflow, I found topic about JS values and references.

If anyone is interested and too lazy to read the topic, you can look at this example. It's pretty much self explanatory.

```
function test(){
    var a = 5;
    var b = a; //b now has value of 5
    console.log("a:"+a+":b:"+b);
    b = 4;//a still has value of 5 and b is assinged to 4
    console.log("a:"+a+":b:"+b);
    var c = {val:1};
    var d = c; //d now has reference to c
    d.val = 2; //c.val changes because it is a reference
    console.log(c);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`console.log` delays converting values to string until the application slows down so that logging doesn't slow down the application unnecessarily.

If the `console.log(position)` is showing a value that is different from that at the time `console.log` was called its because the `position` has been modified between the call and the time the console widget decided to format the value for display.

You can see this by trying the following HTML:

```
<script>
// Emits the JSON form when converted to a string.
var obj = {
  x: 1,
  toString: function () {
    return JSON.stringify(this);
  }
};

console.log(obj);  // Often {x:2}
console.log("" + obj);  // Reliably {x:1}  

obj.x = 2;
</script>
```

Look for code that does something like

```
obj = getPosition(...);
...
obj.y = <expression that evaluates to zero>
```

Alternatively, you can force eager formatting by changing

```
 console.log(position)
```

to

```
 console.log("" + position)
```

Comment: Ok, so now I know why is it possible to see two different values, but I cant find what I'm doing wrong in my code. I even change the names so that it doesn't overlap or something. How do I find out where's the problem?

Comment: @VytautusButkus, if you have Firefox handy, you can probably use [`Object.watch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch) to install a property breakpoint on the `y` property of obj so you can dump `console.trace()` or `throw` when code modifies it.

Comment: Strange behaviour, if i set watch for object it get correct value, but as soon as I comment it out it comes back to wrong value. Any other tips?

Comment: Look at this:Object { x=8, y=0} and when I click on it http://i39.tinypic.com/972v7n.png for some reason it shows 0 in console, but when I open it in DOM it's 3

Comment: @VytautasButkus, your watcher might be vetoing changes.

Comment: Ok, even if it's vetoing it doesnt matter, but how would anyone explain different values in DOM and in JSON itself?